# Language AND region selector

Tags: 7, views, i18n-l10n

I'm asked to build a website which allows visitors to select both a language **and** a region, together, so it's a set of combined choices (eg. one choice would be "Switzerland French", another would be "Switzerland German", and so on). (Right now it's a combination of two countries and two languages, but it may be extended to other countries or languages in the future.)

This choice then accompany the visitor everywhere on the site, until of course she decides to change it. (The selector will be visible on all pages.)

Based on this choice:

- a **language** is set (the site will be localized),
- some contents (based on Views) will be **ordered** differently, and some will be filtered out,
- some contents (blocks or pages) will be made visible or not,
- the rest of the contents remain accessible and basically unchanged (but localized).

I'm not completely new to Drupal, but I'm no Drupal guru either. And I have no idea on how to implement that.

Can you advise me on how to approach this?

Comment: Enable Drupals default Locale module.

Comment: Already done. But I don't see how it helps me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the absence of any other answer, I've decided to try using the [Organic Group](https://drupal.org/project/og) module to solve this case.
I made this choice after reading [this article](http://www.bluespark.com/blog/architecting-multi-country-site-drupal-7) which is the closest I've found to my needs.

However, I'm still not entirely sure that this is the only or even the best solution, so any other suggestion is still welcome.